# Why can't I reduce urllib.parse.urljoin?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, reduce

Given

```
paths = ("http://localhost:5000", "api", "v1")
```

I expect

```
from functools import reduce
from urllib.parse import urljoin

reduce(urljoin, paths)
```

to yield

```
"http://localhost:5000/api/v1"
```

but it actually yields

```
"http://localhost:5000/v1"
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because you don't have a trailing slash on the intermediate `http://localhost:5000/api`

Comment: See the example in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin), which illustrates the behaviour. That's how it determines the "base", it's not just the whole of the first argument.

Comment: I might be missing how `v1` is any better of a candidate than `api` in the selection process, but I'd 100% expect this to raise an error instead of implicitly filtering.

Comment: Or, in the case of just `urljoin`, not simply return the `base`.